# Obtaining file names from directory in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, testing, zsh

I am trying to create a zsh script to test my project. The teacher supplied us with some input files and expected output files. I need to diff the output files from myExecutable with the expected output files.

#### Question: Does `$iF` contain a string in the following code or some kind of bash reference to the file?

```
#!/bin/bash
inputFiles=~/project/tests/input/*
outputFiles=~/project/tests/output

for iF in $inputFiles
do
./myExecutable $iF > $outputFiles/$iF.out
done
```

#### Note:

Any tips in fulfilling my objectives would be nice. I am new to shell scripting and I am using the following websites to quickly write the script (since I have to focus on the project development and not wasting time on extra stuff):

[Grammar for bash language](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar)

[Begginer guide for bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)

Comment: Why not use the `diff` command ?

Comment: Are you using `zsh` or `bash` here? Because they aren't the same. Also what objective are you trying to accomplish here. The quoted question asks one thing but your question seems to ask another.

Comment: I am using zsh. I was learning from bash websites in the hope that some of the bash code would be valid in zsh. I am aware they are different. Just not aware of many differences. The question is related to the title.

Comment: I will be using the diff command. Just trying to get the files into a folder for now. I intend to place the diff output in another folder as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is, `$iF` contains full path of file as a string.

N.B: Don't use `for iF in $inputFiles`

use `for iF in ~/project/tests/input/*` instead. Otherwise your code will fail if path contains spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to diff the files you can do another for loop on your output files. Grab just the file name with the *basename* command and then put that all together in a diff and output to a ".diff" file using the ">" operator to redirect standard out.

Then diff each one with the expected file, something like:

```
expectedOutput=~/<some path here>
diffFiles=~/<some path>

for oF in ~/project/tests/output/* ; do
file=`basename ${oF}`
diff $oF "${expectedOutput}/${file}" > "${diffFiles}/${file}.diff"
done
```